# Is there any way to += an innerHTML in reactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a text onto a div which is rendered with the RenderPage() function and exported to an index.js file to be rendered, is there any way to add a text to a div with innerHTML += 'asdf'

I have tried `document.getElementsByClassName('preview').innerHTML = itemsThingy[0] + count['matcha']`

But it doesn't seem to render it...

Comment: In React you shouldn't use `innerHTML` or `getElementBy..`. You can use data binding and state. For example: `<div>{this.state.preview}</div>` will always show the contents of the `preview` variable in the div.

Comment: So for example like this? ```<div>{itemsThingy[0] + count['matcha']}</div>```

Comment: Yes, but the variable has to come from the state if you want the DOM to update once the variable changes. For example, `<div>{this.state.itemsThingy[0] + this.state.count['matcha']}</div>`. You have to set the initial state in the constructor: `this.state = {itemsThingy:[], count:[]}`

Comment: You can practice this right on the homepage of React if you scroll down a bit: https://reactjs.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate the DOM in React - you can still set innerHTML, but to do this you have to use the function `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` instead, which indicates this is not a good practice and should pretty much never be done.

There are many other ways to achieve the same results you're looking for in React without having to manipulate the DOM - you can conditionally render JSX, or use lazy-loading with suspense depending on your specific usecase.